Does OpenJDK 13 container image support cgroup v2?
We are experiencing OOM errors in some of our legacy services running on OpenJDK 13 (adoptopenjdk:13-jdk-hotspot container images) on an EKS cluster (version 1.28 running on bottlerocket nodes).
In the kubernetes docs we see

If you deploy Java applications, prefer to use versions which fully support cgroup v2:
OpenJDK / HotSpot: jdk8u372, 11.0.16, 15 and later

Does this mean that only versions 15 and newer support cgroup v2, or that version 15 supports it out of the box, while other non-LTS versions might still have it included in some hotfix?
Specifically, does the image adoptopenjdk:13-jdk-hotspot support cgroup v2?
Additionally, is there a way for us to check it ourselves?
We suspect that our problems result from lack of cgroup v2 support because our other services running on OpenJDK 11.0.2 also OOM'ed until we bumped them to OpenJDK 11.0.16.

I type "openjdk cgroup v2" into Google. The first hit is this issue ticket about it with the fix version set to 15. At some point, you just have to acknowledge that you have to upgrade. Java 13 isn't even an LTS version, you should be on at least Java 17 by now.

@Gimby And that ticket was backported to Java 8 and Java 11 as those are LTS versions.

I'm not sure why you're asking this question. The text you quote explicitly says it's in Java 8 update 372 or higher, Java 11.0.16 or higher, or Java 15 or later. Java 13 does not come in the picture. Being a non-LTS, it is not subject to backports from newer major versions, because support of non-LTS versions stops when a new major version is released. And you really, really shouldn't be using Java 13 in production any more. Support for that version ended in March 2020, 4.5 years ago.

Thank you for your comments. I was not aware of the fact that only LTS versions are subject to backports. I know we shouldn’t use Java 13 anymore, that’s why I called it a “legacy service” :)
